# disable click (Data binding)on Hyperlink using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, data-binding, knockout.js, hyperlink

I want to disable the hyperlink(do nothing when click on it) for some conditions (to do Field validation before) 
problem in  data-bind="click: Send" , i couldn't disable this.

```
  <ul class="pager wizard">

    <li class="previous"><a href="#">Etape Précédente</a></     
    <li class="next" data-bind="foreach: personnelInfo " ><a href="#" id="idInfo" data-bind="click: Send">Etape Suivante info</a></li>

  </ul>
```

this is not working

```
$('#idInfo').click(function () {
            return false;
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla JS:

```
document.getElementById("idInfo").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

And for jQuery:

```
$("#idInfo").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Note how in both examples, I passed the event object into the functions as a argument.